# Defining a duplicate foreign key in a ViewModel

Tags: c#, database, model-view-controller, razor, viewmodel

I'm using a ViewModel to set some data on a page (two dropdownlists), and other data is simply being submitted on a new user creation.

For example, I have 3 tables. Users, Classes, ContactInfo

If both my Classes and ContactInfo table have a foreign key "UserId" to the User table, how do I differentiate them?

```
namespace School.ViewModels{

    public class newStudentPage{ 

         //student table (model)
         public string Name{ get; set;}
         public string LastName{ get; set;}

         //contact table (model)
         public int UserId{ get; set;}
         public string Phone{ get; set;}


         //class table (model)
         public int UserId{ get; set;} 
         public string Class{ get; set;}
    }
}
```

When the user submits the form, I'll create a new user, have the primary key returned, and use that to submit to the other two tables for entries.

But I need to differentiate these foreign keys.

What is the correct means of doing this?

Comment: There is no need to use the Property Name UserId, You can put the [ForeignKey(<name of integer Property>] property, on the related property; Class or Phone or whatever you have here. The id-name can be whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you, can you show an example, or tell me what that is conventionally referred to as? So I may search for examples.

Comment: I guess I'm slightly confused as to *how* my ViewModel knows which model to which I'm referring. It must find the property by name, if only one name exists. Otherwise you'd have to call it something else, but still somehow be directing that ViewModel property to the specific Model and property in my particular situation.

Comment: If you present only one class, we cannot talk about relations. You create text about Users, Classes, ContactInfo, then you come up with Code for newStudentPage.
If you have two UserID, I would expect you should have two User Properties also.

Comment: Well the idea is that I will submit a user with his/her basic data; retrieve the new PrimaryKey UserID, and submit that ID with the class data and the contact data. Does that make sense?

Comment: Either you talk about storing the users data. Or you store the UserID, as a reference to an existing user in another table. But not both. Stop talking about inserting and submitting and staff, we are defining just relations here. You talked about 3 tables, you have shown only the code for 1 table.
If UserID is the primary key, it does not make sense to have two of them.
Do you create two keys, to have two relations  ? That is not necessary. One key for both is enough.

Comment: The UserID is the primary key in the User table. 

UserID is a foreign key in both the class and contact table; to tie those rows to the User row.

    DB.User
    -UserID (PK)
    -Name

    DBClass
    -ClassID
    -UserID (FK)
    -ClassName

    DBContact
    -ContactID
    -UserID (FK)
    -PhoneNumber

So to use the get;set; of the ViewModel, for example, I would insert a number to phone number, and I can target the DBContact.PhoneNumber,

But if I aim to insert to DBContact UserID, I need to differentiate between the DBContact and DBClass table. Does that make sense?

Comment: I apologize for the formatting

Comment: Your code is not related to your Text !!!! There are no classes User, Class or Contact in your sample. By your description, every of your three tables has one UserID, and everything is fine. (for one table it's the primary key, for the others a foreign key).
Every row in any table is associated to one specific user, in this way. What else do you want ?
Your first two sentences are completely correct. I don't get the point, how you confuse yourself. Especially, because you don't show your code.
Are you using Entity Framework and LINQ, or do you try to build database-relations manually ?

Comment: You have one List<DBContact> and one List<DBClass> and those two lists is your 'differentiation', you search in one, for phone number, you search in the other for something else. You search for it, maybe this is the point you haven't got.